# Change parameter type

Tags: c#, .net, expression

I have an `Expression` instance (not generic). It is actually of type `Expression<Func<TModel, bool>>` and I need to create a new one of type `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>` by changing the type of incoming parameter. What is the easiest and complete solution for this?

**MISSED INFO:**

`Model`'s and `Entity`'s properties that take part in the expressions are equals.

Comment: What is the conversion path from TModel to TEntity?

Comment: There's lots of information missing from your question such as the relation between the `TModel` and `TEntity` classes and how exactly do you intend to perform this substitution. Changing only the parameter type of an expression would completely break it without reflecting those changes in the expression itself. This looks like an ASP.NET MVC requirement. Could you state your original problem? I am sure we could find an easy solution to it.

Comment: Sorry, I thought but missed that point in question. Take a look on the  edit.